# Are there any possible ways to download videos using iframe

Tags: javascript, java, api, video, iframe

Is there any way to download videos using src link of iframe tag using java or javascript or any other way.

Comment: What actual content is within the iFrame? If you have the URL of the video, simply go to that URL and it will download.

Comment: If you are trying to download videos from YouTube, note that Google does not like that.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.